# IIF Parameter expression like value or any

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to have a parameter when set as something other than "Any", perform a "LIKE" search in SSRS.

I am adding an expression to some code to search for values like the ones entered in as a parameter. If nothing is entered then return all.

Essentially, the user wants to be able to enter names into the UserId parameter and then get a result set where UserID's = whatever is entered. If nothing is entered then return all of them. I attempted to do this with the code below, but it is failing and I think its because I used a "Like" in an expression, it could also be the %'s.

```
+ IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!UserID.Value," ANY") > -1, "", " AND u.userid like ('%'" +(Parameters!UserID.Value,"'',''") + "'%') ")
```

The expected results would be something along the lines of:

@userID parameter = @gmail.com 
Result set only shows user ID's with that email address portion

Or 
@userID parameter = Jamie
Result set only shows User ID's with the name Jamie in it

Or

@userID parameter = " Any" (set as default value in SSRS)
Result set shows all User I's

Comment: I ended up doing this:

+ IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!UserID.Value," ANY") > -1, "", " AND c.userid like ''%''+(''" + Join(Parameters!UserID.Value,"'',''") + "'')+''%'' ")

Answer (score 0):

In your query condition can be something like
WHERE fieldname LIKE '%' + @test + '%'

OR

adding a filter expression with a like operator and setting the value to this:
="*" + Parameters!Roles.Value + "*"
To get all values you pass

Comment: So you are saying something like this:

    + IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!UserID.Value," ANY") > -1, "", " AND u.userid like (''" + (Parameters!UserID.Value) + "'') ")

Comment: You can use isnothing function something like iif(isnothing(parametervalue),then show everything,like condition)